# Spring Step Scoped beans do not respect @Order annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

When I create 2 beans with `@StepScope` and apply `@Order` then the order for both beans still gets resolved to `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` when trying to autowire them as a List.

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
@StepScope
public MyBean bean1(
    return new MyBean("1");
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
@StepScope
public MyBean bean2(
    return new MyBean("2");
}
```

Looking in `OrderComparator` I see the beans are resolved to a source of `ScopedProxyFactoryBean` which returns a null order value.
Wondering if Im doing something wrong here as I would expect the ordering to work correctly.

So the aim in to autowire an ordered list into another bean eg

```
@Component   
public class OuterBean {
  private List<MyBean> beans;
  public OuterBean(List<MyBean> beans) {
    this.beans = beans;
  }
}
```

And I would expect the list to contain `{bean1,bean2}`

Comment: Can you explain your use case please? How are those beans used? Are you trying to inject one of them in a step and expecting the bean marked with `@Order(1)` to take precedence? Please share how those beans are used to understand the use case. I'm just trying to make sure there is no confusion between `@Order` and `@Primary` .

Comment: Ive added to the description to clarify what I hope to achieve

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer with a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Step scoped beans need to be used in the scope of a running step. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Configuration
public class MyJob {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    @StepScope
    public MyBean bean1() {
        return new MyBean("1");
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    @StepScope
    public MyBean bean2() {
        return new MyBean("2");
    }

    @Bean
    public OuterBean outerBean(List<MyBean> beans) {
        return new OuterBean(beans);
    }

    @Bean
    public Tasklet tasklet(OuterBean outerBean) {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            outerBean.sayHello();
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .tasklet(tasklet(null))
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

}
```

The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/master/issues/so61836412). This example prints:

```
bean = 1
bean = 2
```

which means step scoped beans have been injected in the right order.